# Riichi Mahjong on PS4 Game "Judgement"

Tags: mahjong, riichi-mahjong

I came across Mahjong whilst playing a Playstation game called "Judgement".  I enjoyed it so much I bought a set and got my family playing it.  Now we have regularly Mahjong evenings.

However, frustratingly, when I return to the Playstation game I find that hands which I believe should win, do not / or are not allowed.  I don't know if the game is getting something wrong or me?

For example, why is the following hand (at bottom of screen) not Tanyao i.e. all simples / no terminals?

[image: Tanyao]

Comment: Bonus configurations like tanyao are rarely used in Mah Jong.  Presumably they simply aren't part of the game you're using.

Comment: But as far as you are concerned it is a valid hand in Riichi Mahjong?

Comment: It depends on the house rules.  In the rules I've played in the family - yes. In the rules of the club I currently belong to - no.  In the gambling rules that some relatives of mine play - you would be penalised for attempting to lay that hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The yaku in the shown hand is Kuitan, not Tanyao.**

Tanyao (All Simples) is a standard Yaku, but it applies to closed hands, which that pictured hand is not due to the two claimed discards. There are house rules that allow for Open All Simples, known as Kuitan (which gets its name from being Tanyao formed by "eating" discards).

From a brief bit of googling, there appears to be an option in that game that you can set to enable or disable Kuitan - if that option is **disabled**, then Kuitan is not considered a valid Yaku, and you won't be allowed to go out with All Simples if your hand is open. I suspect in your case, that option was disabled.

Comment: I literally found the Kuitan setting in the game last night and Googled it to learn exactly what you just explained.  Thanks for taking the time out to explain - it was driving me mad.

Comment: For anyone else coming here after playing Judgement they may also notice that occasional their dragon pon hand isn't allowed, but at other times it is.  I discovered there is also an option in the settings which defaults to requiring a minimum of 2 han in order for a hand to be valid.  Turn that off and a dragon pon always allows you to go out.

Comment: Kuitan is normally considered a type of tan'yao, not a different yaku. E.g., in MahjongSoul, characters will announce "tan'yao" when scoring their hand whether it was open or not.